# Accessing UIView methods

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a UIViewController that contains a UITabBarController, which contains a UIViewController, e.g.:

```
UIViewController1 -> UITabBarController -> UIViewController2
```

I want to hook up a button in `UIViewController2` that will call a method in `UIViewController1`, but how do I access `UIViewController1` from `UIViewController2`?  I know that calling `self.parentViewController` from `UIViewController2` gets me to the `UITabBarController`, but where do I go from there?

I tried `self.parentViewController.parentViewController` from UIViewController2, but got `null`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Note that making a UITabBarController a subview of another view is a contravention of Apple application design guidelines.  See the View Controller Programming Guide: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CombiningViewControllers/CombiningViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH104-SW1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `self.parent.parent` technique often won't work because there may be Apple implementation layers in-between your controllers.  Best to create pointers yourself in your own implementation by subclassing and creating instance variables, and setting them at the point of creation.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this depending on what your actually trying to solve....for example if its a utility like class method then you should put it in a different file and import it into UIViewController2.  If its an instance method then you obviously have an instance of UIViewController1 then you need to declare an instance variable of type UIViewController1 that holds a reference to the view controller.  Then you can call methods on that instance....what is it that you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am using the `UITabBarController` to break `UIViewController1` into different "pages" (otherwise it would be an extremely long scroll view) so that it feels better on the iPhone.  `UIViewController2` is just displays one grouping of information about related objects. So when you click on one of them I want to push a detailViewController for the related object onto the UINavigationController which lives in `UIViewController1`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the first one as a property and assign it when you instantiate:

```
viewController1.otherView = viewController2;
```